# Trying to create a symbolic link to save space on sims 4 mods, but the syntax is coming up as wrong

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link

It says my syntax is incorrect, I'm a little stumped. Thank you! This is the code.

`C:\WINDOWS\system32>mklink \d C:\Users\kayle\Documents\"Electronic Arts"\"The Sims 4"\realmods D:\Sims4Mods`

Answer (score 1):

The command to create links might be case-sensitive, you're using the wrong slash, you have your quotations wrong, and the link/target is backwards.

When the file path has a space, the quotation has to be around the entire path, not just the part with the space.

When doing the command where you want to symbolic link to go, comes first, and then the original file path comes second.

For your command you'll want to run the CMD as administrator and then the syntax goes `mklink /D Link Target`

`mklink /D D:\Sims4Mods "C:\Users\kayle\Documents\Electronic Arts\The Sims 4\realmods"`

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the correct switch is `/d`, not `\d`. If you are using `\d`, this might be the source of your issue.

Also, you should wrap the whole link directory in double quotes (removing the ones you currently have). So your final command might be:

`mklink /d "C:\Users\kayle\Documents\Electronic Arts\The Sims 4\realmods" D:\Sims4Mods`

(This assumes `realmods` is the symbolic link you wish to create and `Sims4Mods` is the directory you wish to create a link to i.e. it contains your mod files.)

You can read more about `mklink` in the [official documentation from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink).

---

**Using Link Shell Extension**

Alternatively, another option to consider might be a utility called [Link Shell Extension](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html). It adds the ability to "pick" an item and to "drop" a symbolic link to it wherever desired, all in the Windows GUI (via the right-click context menu).

---

*Note that Link Shell Extension uses the original item name as the created link name but the created link can then be renamed as normal in Windows.*

---

Scroll to the bottom of the page linked above for downloads. Otherwise, here are (currently) working links to the executables:

- [64-bit Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/HardLinkShellExt_X64.exe) (Includes 32-bit version).
- [32-bit Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/HardLinkShellExt_win32.exe) (Only)

Visual Studio 2015 redistributables may or may not be required, depending on your version of Windows, but can be obtained here (as needed):

- [VS 15 64-bit Redistributables](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vc_redist.x64.exe)
- [VS 15 32-bit Redistributables](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vc_redist.x86.exe)

You may also wish to check out the `/noredist` option for Link Shell Extension on the original website.

**Link Shell Extension (Example Use)**

*ex. Pick Link Source (dat.dat)*

[image: Link Shell Extension - Pick Link - Remote Image]

*ex. Drop Link (use Symbolic Link)*

[image: Link Shell Extension - Drop Link - Remote Image]

*ex. Cancel Link Creation (if we change our minds)*

[image: Link Shell Extension - Cancel Link - Remote Image]